# How to pass list containing desired arguments to a function

Tags: java, arrays

So I have an object, lets call it myObject

Here are the constructors to my object

```java
private static class myObject {
        public myObject(int argA) {
            this.argA = argA;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, boolean argB) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argB = argB;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, int argC, int argD) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argC = argC;
            this.argD = argD;
        }

        public myObject(int argA, String argE) {
            this.argA = argA;
            this.argE = argE;
        }


        public int argA = 1;
        public boolean argB;
        public int argC = 4;
        public int argD = 5;
        public String argE;
```

Now I want to create an instance of myObject but I am receiving a list of parameters for it. For example I'm given

```java
List objectParams = Arrays.asList(1,3,4)
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters = ?;
```

So this should use the 3rd constructor since its 3 ints.

I could also get a list of 2 arguments or a list of 1 argument.

How can I convert this list to be taken in by my constructor?

Comment: Will your list always have 3 `int`s? (i.e. Will it always use the third constructor?)

Comment: No, the list can have any number of elements in it. (It can be intended to use the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... constructors) I'm just not sure how do I pass this list cleanly into my constructor.

Comment: What you're asking for seems very similar to python's tuple unpacking, but this doesn't really exist in Java. It's theoretically possible to hack this together, but it would be much cleaner to restructure your code instead.

Comment: Are you asking for this specific `class` with this specific list of constructors? Or are you asking for code which works for `class`es with different constructors?

Comment: I suggest having a single constructor with [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) and assume a specific order, similar to the way that method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) works.

Answer (score 0):

If your always want to use the third constructor (with 3 `int`s), you can simply use the following:

```
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters = new myObject((int) objectParams.get(0), (int) objectParams.get(1), (int) objectParams.get(2));.
```

Otherwise, you will need to test the structure of the list to determine which constructor to use:

```
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters;
if (objectParams.size() == 1)
    newObjectWithTheseParameters = new myObject((int) objectParams.get(0));
else if (objectParams.size() == 2 && objectParams.get(1) instanceof Boolean)
    newObjectWithTheseParameters = new myObject((int) objectParams.get(0), (boolean) objectParams.get(1));
else if (objectParams.size() == 3)
    newObjectWithTheseParameters = new myObject((int) objectParams.get(0), (int) objectParams.get(1), (int) objectParams.get(2));
else if (objectParams.size() == 2 && objectParams.get(2) instanceof String)
    newObjectWithTheseParameters = new myObject((int) objectParams.get(0), (String) objectParams.get(1));
else
    // Handle invalid list.
```

Comment: I understand, thanks.

So I have many constructors which override certain default values defined. Is there any way to convert all these into 1 constructor? Would the best way to do this is to use a builder? However this would increase codebase by alot because I need to call this constructor ~100 times and it goes from a simple 1 liner to a build method call

Comment: @PLfan666 Sorry for the delayed response. You could have the constructor accept the List as a parameter and move the if statements inside the constructor. Then, move or copy whatever code you already have in each individual constructor to its respective if statement. However, this unfortunately does not allow you to call a different superconstructor or delegate to a different constructor depending on the input types, as that has to be the first statement of your constructor.